# Adding and removing ftp users in Proftpd by shell script

Tags: shell, ftp, proftpd

I am  stuck with a shell script

Add and remove ftp users. The script should take username and home directory as argument. The password prompt should be securely entered without viewing.

The script should test that the new user can indeed upload and download files using passive mode of operation.

(Proftpd compiled from source)

Comment: What did you write so far?

Comment: compiled and installed Proftpd with  ./configure --sysconfdir=/etc 
make make install.

Comment: I don't understand. You said that you are stuck with a shell script. So show us what you wrote so far.

Comment: I have put all compilation steps including ./configure make and make install steps in a shell script and now needed to add and remove ftp users through same shell script

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.